# Navbar with only two buttons, one on the left and one to the right, and a rectangular logo in the middle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am extremely new to StackOverflow, and relatively new to HTML/CSS. My question, as the title of this suggests, is how do I make a navbar with only two buttons "Menu" and "Contact Us", Menu being to the left and contact us to the right, and put a rectangular logo in the middle? I am constantly searching online, and there are always some parts I get stuck at so I have to redo it all. I am using bootstrap, and I know that to align I need to float each one to its intended position. But since I am new, there are always some concepts I get stuck at. May someone tell me how I can build this navbar? With or without Bootstrap.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site.   We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: You should really include your code, what specific problem you are running into etc. Stackoverflow is not a coding service but we can point you into the right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you have a way to start with: [NavBar](https://medium.com/flexbox-and-grids/the-most-popular-navigation-bars-created-with-flexbox-6c0f59f55686)

Or you can check this snippet made with the guide mentioned above:

You can edit this NavBar as you want, I recommend you to check the article if you want to learn more about FlexBox.

```css
main {
   width: 70%
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.twitter {
  display: flex;
}
.twitter__bird {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

.twitter {
  height: 46px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(238,238,238 ,1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgba(117,117,117 ,1);
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px -20px rgba(85,172,238 ,1);
}
.twitter li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.twitter li:hover{
  color: rgba(85,172,238 ,1);
}
.twitter__bird {
  color: rgba(85,172,238 ,1);
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.twitter li:not(:last-child):not(.twitter__bird) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.twitter li  i:not(.fa-twitter):not(.fa-search):not(.fa-user-circle-o) {
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.twitter li > button {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border: 0;
  background: rgba(85,172,238 ,1);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="twitter" role="navigation">
  <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</li>
  <li class="twitter__bird"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```